# Synchronize a circular buffer with the write and the read operation without a lock

Tags: c, multithreading, locking, buffer, circular-buffer

I have a circular buffer which can store image frames, say 30 frames and there's a thread that keeps writing to the buffer on its own. There is a main thread which reads data from the buffer and copies the data to another buffer.

The problem is I cannot synchronize the circular buffer with the write and the read operation. I cannot lock the circular buffer because the write operation is done by a thread that I don't have the access.

Is there a way to check from the main thread that the frame the main thread is reading is not overwritten ?

Comment: Are you looking for a [fence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn899125(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: Sounds more like looking for *magic* :o for any kind of synchronization, *both* sides have to participate. Maybe (!) there *might* be some other way to solve the problem if you would show code / explain the situation in detail.

Comment: Yeah.. sounds like this design is irretrievably broken.  Also, buffers cotaining such large amounts of data as image files should not be bulk-copied unless absolutely unavoidable.  You have malloc, pointers and could also build buffer pools.

Comment: "Is there a way to check from the main thread that the frame the main thread is reading is not overwritten ?" Read it twice.  If it is the same, then it was not overwritten in a way that makes a difference.

Comment: @MartinJames Agreed some lock, flags, etc are preferable, yet OP asked "Is there a way"? The 2x idea implies the _read_ thread can read the complete frame at least once, before the the _write_ thread can modify it twice.

Comment: @chux *Read it twice.*  Doesn't really work - what if the reader thread reads it twice while the writer thread is blocked halfway through writing a copy?  Both copies are the same, and they're both incomplete/incorrect. Without access to the writer code, that can't be ruled out. And of course, if it is correct, then you have to read it again, to make sure it hasn't changed in the time after the two reads...

Comment: @AndrewHenle Good point.  With such an a-synchronized system, I would have added sequence numbers to book-end the data to detect the issue you suggest.  Yet we do not know what changes are possible as post lacks details.

Answer (score 0):

Is your design flexible? If yes then use concept of Paging, which is always useful in Circular Buffer Problem. Please mention your design so that one can help you.

Else you might be writing Frames in Buffer with time-stamp, so use it to verify whether Frame is overwritten or not.

Sorry! "StackOverFlow", I broke your rule "Avoid asking for clarification in answers",I did because I can't comment on this question, as I don't have "50 reputation".